# Aftermarket Xbox 360 Wireless Adapter no longer works in Windows 10 (Worked in Windows 7 since 2012)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, xbox360, game-controller

Following these steps used to work. I'm able to try installing the two different drivers 32-bit Version 2 and 64-bit Version 10, but neither work anymore. I've tried multiple Windows 10 machines, and multiple USB ports.

```
You can download the driver needed for Windows 7 by following these directions:

Right click on Computer
Go to Properties
Click on Device Manager
Right click on the Unidentified Device
Go to Properties
Go to the Driver tab
Click on Update Driver…
Browse my computer for driver software
Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
Microsoft Common Controller for Window Class
Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 2.1.0.1349 [8/13/2009]
Update Driver Warning
Click Yes
```

Comment: Are you sure the adapter is still functional?  I personally had to replace my Xbox 360 Adapter, after one day, it refused to work.  I suspect based on the fact, it does not function on multiple machines, the adapter is not functional.  Windows 8+ have the Xbox 360 driver, the driver described in the quoted text, isn't applicable to Windows 10.  I can confirm my Xbox wireless 360 adapter works on every version of Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound quite possibly. Is your adapter an official Microsoft one or an aftermarket one from China?

Comment: Technically, any adapter you buy is a generic adapter, because the official adapter was discontinued years ago.  So my original adapter was officially, my replacement, was an official generic.